# A guess related to Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

When I read Lebesgue differentiation theorem, I suddenly have the following conjecture, which I can't prove or find a counterexample.

> Let $f\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If 
>   $$
> \int_{B_r(x)} f(y)dy=0
> $$
>   holds for **any $r\geq 1$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$**, then can we say that $f(x)=0$ a.e. ? Please be careful that **$r$ is larger than 1**, which prevents us from taking advantage of  Lebesgue differentiation theorem. When $n=1$, this seems to be true.

Comment: sorry but just lead $r\to 0$ after dividing by the volume of the ball $b_r(x)$to get the answer.

Comment: @GuyFsone that is the problem, here $r$ is large than 1. you can't let $r\to 0$. I have edited the problem so that other people would be careful

Answer (score 6):

Fix $n$ and let $\mathcal Z\subseteq L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the class of solutions $f$ to your equation
$$
\int_{B_r(x)} f(y)dy=0\text{ for all $r\geq 1$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.}
$$

$\mathcal Z$ has several nice symmetries:

- Isometries. If $f\in\mathcal Z$ and $g$ is an isometry of $\mathbb R^n$, then $g\star f\in \mathcal Z$ where $(g\star f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$. This is because the set of spheres of radius $r\geq 1$ is preserved by isometries.
- Partial integrals. If $T$ is a manifold equipped with a measure, and $F:T\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a measurable function such that $F$ is absolutely integrable on $T\times C$ for compact sets $C\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and such that $F(t,\cdot)\in \mathcal Z$ for almost every $t\in T$, then by Fubini's theorem $f\in\mathcal Z$ where $f$ is the partial integral defined by $f(x)=\int_{t\in T} F(t,x)dt$.
- Convolution by bounded compactly supported functions $\psi:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. This is a type of partial integral $F(t,x)=f(x-t)\psi(t)$.
- Averaging over the orthogonal group $O(n)$. This is a partial integral $\bar{f}(x)=\int_{g\in O(n)}(g\star f)(x)$. Note this preserves smoothness - the derivatives are just a similar integral over $O(n)$ but with the direction of the derivative varying with $g$.

Therefore, given a function $f\in\mathcal Z$ that is not almost everywhere zero:

- We can assume $f$ is smooth by convolving with a compactly supported [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). (The usual Lebesgue differentiation theorem can be used to show this doesn't result in the zero function.)
- We can then assume $f(0)\neq 0$ by translating.
- We can then assume that $f$ is radially symmetric by averaging over the orthogonal group, which replaces $f(x)$ by the average of $f$ over the sphere of radius $|x|$.

So $f$ is a smooth radially symmetric function. For $r>1$, the function $I(r)=\int_{B_r(0)}f(y)dy$ is zero, so its derivative $I'(r)=\int_{S_r(0)}f(y)dy$ is zero, where $S_r(0)$ denotes the sphere of radius $r$ around $0$. But $f(y)$ is constant in $S_r(0)$, so
$$f(x)=0\text{ for all $|x|>1$.}$$

Then:

- If we can show that the [Radon transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) of $f$ is zero, then $f$ is zero. So pick a hyperplane $H=\{x\mid (x\cdot n)=c\}$. Consider the sphere $S_R(n(c+R))$ tangent to $H$ at $nc$, with $R$ large - it is geometrically clear that the intersection of $S_R(n(c+R))\cap B_1(0)$ is approximately the same as $H\cap B_1(0)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\int_{S_R(n(c+R))} f \to \int_{H} f$ as $R\to\infty$. We showed before that the integral of $f$ on a sphere of radius at least $1$ is zero, so $\int_{H} f$ is zero as required.
- Alternatively, use the fact that $f$ is in $L_1$ so its Fourier transform is a function $\hat f\in L_\infty$, not almost everywhere zero. The Fourier transform $\widehat{\chi_{B_1(0)}}$ of the indicator function of the unit ball is almost everywhere non-zero; see [this explicit description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489391/fourier-transform-of-the-indicator-of-the-unit-ball) or use [Schwarz's Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz.27s_Paley.E2.80.93Wiener_theorem). But if $f\in\mathcal Z$, then the convolution of $f$ by $\chi_{B_1(0)}$ is everywhere zero, so by the $L_1$ convolution theorem the product $\hat f\widehat{\chi_{B_1(0)}}$ is everywhere zero, which implies $\hat f$ is almost everywhere zero, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Wauzl: which part do you want elaborated? I am assuming it is clear that the condition of having a zero integral over balls of radius $\geq 1$ is invariant under isometries and linear combinations.

Comment: How do you exactly do the averaging? Can this be done with a convolution, as well? Why does $f$ vanish for $|x|>1$? How is the approximation of the integral of $f$ along a hyperplane approximated by the integral over a large sphere done? Sorry, I'm not very deep into the matter. But maybe, by explaining your steps a bit more, a beginner might be able to understand your proof, as well.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ it is true.

> **Claim:** Suppose $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $$\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(y)dy=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $r\ge1$. Then
>   $$\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(y)dy=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $r>0$.

**Proof:** Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$. Then
$$0=\int_{x+r-2R}^{x+r}f(y)dy - \int_{x-r-2R}^{x-r}f(y)dy = \int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(y)dy - \int_{x-r-2R}^{x+r-2R}f(y)dy$$
for all $R\ge1$. By taking different choices of $R$, it follows immediately that
$$\int_{x'-r}^{x'+r}f(y)dy$$
is independent of $x'\in\mathbb{R}$, and therefore it must be $0$ by the assumption. The statement follows.

---

I don't know if a similar proof can work for $n\ge2$. If we were able to work with squares instead of balls, then it should, but with balls we get "moons" which are difficult to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n=1.$ For $x>0,$ define$F(x)=\int_{-2}^x f(t)\,dt.$ By hypothesis, $F(x) = 0$ for $x>0.$ Therefore $F'(x) = 0$ on $(0,\infty).$ But by the LDT, $F'(x) = f(x)$ for a.e. $x\in \mathbb R.$ Thus $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x>0.$ Apply this to $f(-x)$ to then see $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x\in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct, but maybe the idea could work. Fix $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $d=|x-y|\geq2$. Let $z=(x+y)/2$ be the midpoint. Let $z_\delta^+=x+(1+\delta)(y-x)/2$ and $z_\delta^-=x+(1-\delta)(y-x)/2$, for $\delta>0$ small. By hypothesis, $$0=\int_{B(z_\delta^+,d/2)} f-\int_{B(z_\delta^-,d/2)} f=\int_{A_\delta^+} f-\int_{A_\delta^-} f,$$ where $$A_\delta^+=B(z_\delta^+,d/2)\backslash (B(z_\delta^+,d/2)\cap B(z_\delta^-,d/2))$$ and $$A_\delta^-=B(z_\delta^-,d/2)\backslash (B(z_\delta^+,d/2)\cap B(z_\delta^-,d/2)).$$ Let $A_\delta=|A_\delta^+|=|A_\delta^-|$. We have $$\frac{1}{A_\delta}\int_{A_\delta^+} f=\frac{1}{A_\delta}\int_{A_\delta^-} f.$$ Letting $\delta$ go to $0$, by a version of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, we obtain $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $f$ is constant, so $f=0$.

Comment: Interesting ! This may work

Comment: This looks great! You may have trouble finding a version of the LDT for those shapes however; they shrink too non regularly. It doesn't matter. We can assume $f$ is continuous by convolving with a nice mollifier with compact support. And for continuous functions, your proof works. +1

Comment: $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\tfrac 1 \delta(\int_{A_\delta^+}f-\int_{A_\delta^-}f)$ is not generally proportional to $f(x)-f(y)$, it is the integral of $(y-x)\cdot \nabla f$ over $B(z,d/2)$. (Indeed the solutions are closed under convolutions, and derivatives are a form of convolution.)

Comment: In order to apply this version of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, you need that the family has bounded eccentricity. "This means that there exists some fixed $c > 0$ such that each set $U$  from the family is contained in a ball $B$  with $|U|\geq c\,|B|$." (Citation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)) Your "moons" $A_\delta^+$ cannot be contained in arbitrarily small balls.

Comment: @Dap and Wauzi Thanks, I had convinced myself the regions in question were "shrinking" to their "centers" in a kind of moon-shaped way. They don't.