# Value of the Fourier transform of the Euclidean ball in $d$ dimensions at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $B$ stand for the centered Euclidean ball with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ in $d$ dimensions. What is the value of the Fourier transform of the indicator function of B evaluated at the origin?

Comment: This is just the measure/volume of the ball. Wikipedia has a formula for this volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_r$ denote the unit ball with radius $r$, and let $\chi_S$ denote the characteristic function of the set $S$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489391/81360) considers the ball with radius $1$.  To apply it to our situation, note that 
$$
\chi_{B_{1/2}}(\mathbf x) = \chi_{B_1}(2\mathbf x).
$$
With the "time-scaling property" of the Fourier transform (or equivalently after applying a substitution in the integral), we have $\hat{\chi}_{B_{1/2}}(\xi) = \frac 1{2^d} \hat\chi_{B_1}(\xi/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{1}_B(0) = \int 1_B(x) dx= {1 \over 2^d} m B(0,1)$.

Comment: Why the downvote?