# The Fourier transform of $ \begin{cases} 1 & |x|<1\\ 0 & else \end{cases} $ where $x \in \mathbb R^3$ is an elementary function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Consider the following function  **in $\mathbb{R}^3$**

$$ \begin{cases}
1 & |x|<1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

How can we calculate its Fourier transform (again, in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

I tried to use spherical coordinates in order to calculate $$ \intop_{\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:|x|<1\right\} }e^{-i \langle \omega,x \rangle}\text{  }\,dx $$

But it seems impossible to finish the calculations.

I would like to see the right way to calculate this integral (because Im pretty sure using spherical coordinates is not the way although it seems the natural choice for a radial function in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

EDIT:

Followed up question:

As I understand from the post in the comments, there is no elementary solution for general $ n$. But, can we find an elementary solution (which does not involve Bessel's functions?)

Comment: In $\mathbb R^1$, this would be some version of ${\sin x\over x}$, but in higher dimensions it is not as elementary... requiring some Bessel function (which _does_ satisfy the "obvious" differential equation... which makes it not-so-not-elementary).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489391/fourier-transform-of-the-indicator-of-the-unit-ball

Comment: @paulgarrett For the particular case where $n=3 $, there exists an elementary solution? (not involving Bessel functions)?